# How to get this Json format

Tags: php, json, parsing

I want the following **JSON** format for my application

```
([{
  "CUSTOMERID":null,
  "STORENUMBER":null,
  "CUSTOMERNAME":"name",
  "ADDRESS1":" Hyderabad",
  "ADDRESS2":null,
  "CITY":"Sec",
  "STATE":"TR"
}]);
```

But when I use json_encode for my array I get the below format

```
[{
  "CUSTOMERID":null,
  "STORENUMBER":null,
  "CUSTOMERNAME":"name",
  "ADDRESS1":" Hyderabad",
  "ADDRESS2":null,
  "CITY":"Sec",
  "STATE":"TR"
}]
```

I miss the starting `(` and ending `);` .

Comment: The starting and ending parentheses are not valid JSON. If you want them you'll have to add them yourself.

Comment: Are you trying to get JSONP? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/169187). Why do you need the parentheses there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '('.json_encode($data).');';
```